# How to create a new control(Text + button) using SWT?

Tags: java, swt

I am using SWT, I want to create a new control which will include a text(org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text) and a button(org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button),the text is on the left, and the button is on the right.

I spent lots of efforts to find an example, but I haven't found... Could anyone provide me a good example? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at CCombo class. CCombo mimics Combo widget. CCombo is good example to look at for custom widget design.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by extending `Composite`. Whitin the composite you can add any widget as you want with the required layout.

Comment: Thank you Bela! Could you kindly please give me a tutorial?